# Ghostscript PDF printing

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, ghostscript, postscript

I would like to make my own "PDF printer" using Ghostscript.

Most of solutions I find on the internet involve a 3rd party like Redmon to redirect the PS printer to the Gs executable.

**Is there a way to do the same without a 3rd party (other than Gs) ?**

Here is my 2 ideas:

- Bypass the printing driver and generate Postscript directly by software (From GDI to postscript, using maybe a custom device context like the Metafile device context exist)
- Create programmatically a new local port for each document to convert. Maybe using this technique : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1331777/99276

The first solution would be great, but can't find anything about it.

And I am efraid the second is not efficient at all (and detect when the document is fully printed can be tricky)

Update: I used print apis to print in a temp file (the print is synchronous) and then convert the PS file with Gs

Answer (score 1):

Firstly; note that the Windows printing system has been redesigned in Windows Vista and beyond. While the old system still works in WIndows 7 and 8, I am unsure of exactly how usable it is in Windows 10. In Windows 10 everything goes via XPS, and I think (could be wrong) that PostScript is generated by going via XPS first.

Your first idea doesn't sound plausible to me. How can you have a printer (and allow your application to print to it) if you don't have a printer driver ? Even if you could do so, why would you create PostScript from GDI just to send it to Ghostscript and have it create PDF ? It would be far more reasonable to create PDF directly.

In the second case I don't see how adding a new local port would help you at all. Ports are simply where the output of the printer driver is directed. What a Port Monitor (RedMon is a Port Monitor) does is redirect the data stream sent to the port, and 'do something' with it. In the case of Ghostscript + RedMon the 'something' is create a PDF file.

I'm unclear why you don't want to use RedMon, given that you are apparently happy with using Ghostscript. However, if you really don't want to do that then write your own Port Monitor. The process is documented in the Windows Device Driver Development Kit and isn't especially hard. If you get stuck you can even look at the RedMon code as a guide. For example, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/sample-port-monitor)

Comment: They i thought about all of this. 
The idea behind using postscript is that I do not have to draw PDF by myself like y overriding a device context. 
Then the idea behind Local ports is that it output Postscript files on the disc without prompting for a file location like the FILE port does. 
At the end yes I have took a look at redmon source code already. But If its the only solution I guess I will do that.

Comment: Creating a PDF from Windows drawing operations is no harder then creating a PostScript program from the same operations, trust me. Certainly you can create local ports that save to a specific file, but then you need code sitting scanning for that filename and processing it if found. That's possible (early versions of Adobe 'PDF print' capability did this, as did other implementations). but its (comparatively) processor expensive. It also is vulnerable to loss of data if the scanning program crashes and the user prints another file.