# Create a local port for a printer

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to make a installer for a printer driver. for that i need to create a port. for network printers I could create a port by using 'prnport.vbs'.

```
cscript c:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs -a -r [PORTNAME] -h [IPADDRESS] -o raw
```

But this script cannot create a local ports.

I sow [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/08/06/use-powershell-to-create-new-printer-ports/) post but it seems not work for Win7.

Can anyone direct me to a cmd or C# solution to create a local port.

Comment: There's a C++ WinAPI solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/1325485/62576). All of the functions that are used can be imported to C#. I'm sure http://pinvoke.net has declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/92982/Adding-a-Local-Port-through-XcvData-and-C). And it works for me.
I put this as a answer for any one have same problem and missed that post.

Comment: This worked very well and is the only sample that I've found that isn't about adding a TCP port !  I needed to add a very specific non-TCP port :)  This did the trick nicely - great find !

Answer (score 0):

For which Windows versions?

With [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh918359(v=wps.630).aspx)

Add-PrinterPort -Name "NameYourLocalPort:"

With Windows API

[AddPrinter function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: which Windows versions? -> for xp, win7 and up